# How can I list the uploads from a YouTube Channel?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, youtube

I am writing this code to search youtube channels on my website and then list their uploads after clicking on them. However currently my links all on all channels to the last channel listed's uploads and I cant tell how in my code that allows that to happen. Can someone have a look and give me an idea of what is going wrong. You can also try/see the website on [www.youtubebypass.dx.am](http://www.youtubebypass.dx.am)

```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>YouTube</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
<link href="style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>

     function channelsearch(){
             gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyAhXRvLpBIyLlOQ9N0W6qUNNqNrhmQBovY')
             
             gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                     makechannelRequest();
        });
     }
     
      function makechannelRequest() {
        var q = $('#Channelquery').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
        type: 'channel',
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 25
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {
                console.log(response)
                $('#results').empty()
        $("#search-results").html("Search Results");
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                channelTitle = "<h4>"+item.snippet.channelTitle+"</h4>";  
                channelThumburl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                id = item.id.channelId;
                channelThumbimg = '<img id="thumb" src="'+channelThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available.">';                   
                
                $('#results').append("<a onclick=\'ChannelUploadId()'>" + channelTitle + "<br>" + channelThumbimg + "<br>" + "</a>")
        })  
    })  
}
       
     function ChannelUploadId(){
             var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({id: id, part:'contentDetails'});
             request.execute(function(response){
                             console.log(response);
                     var srchItems = response.result.items;
                     $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                     playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

                     
             })
             ChannelUploads(playlistId);
     })
     }
     function ChannelUploads(i){
        console.log(i)
        
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
             
             playlistId: i,
             type:'video',
             order:'date',
             part: 'snippet',
             maxResults: 25
             
     
     });
     request.execute(function(response){
                             console.log(response)
                   $('#results').empty()
                        $("#search-results").html("Search Results");
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = "<h4>"+item.snippet.title+"</h4>";  
                vidThumburl = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                vidChannel = "<h4>"+item.snippet.channelTitle+"</h4>";
                vidPublish = "<h4>"+item.snippet.publishedAt+"</h4>";
                id = item.id.videoId;
                vidThumbimg = '<img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available.">';                   

                $('#results').append("<a onclick=\'getScreenshots(\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+id+"\")'>" + vidTitle + "<br>" + "Published: " +vidPublish + "<br>"+ "Channel: "+vidChannel + "<br>"+ vidThumbimg + "</a><hr>");                      
        })
     })
     
   }
   
   
     

     function keyWordsearch(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyAhXRvLpBIyLlOQ9N0W6qUNNqNrhmQBovY')

        
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                makeRequest();
        });
}
    function makeRequest() {
        var q = $('#query').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
        type: 'video',
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 25
        }); 
        request.execute(function(response)  {
                console.log(response)
                $('#results').empty()
                $("#search-results").html("Search Results");
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = "<h4>"+item.snippet.title+"</h4>";  
                vidThumburl = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                vidChannel = "<h4>"+item.snippet.channelTitle+"</h4>";
                vidPublish = "<h4>"+item.snippet.publishedAt+"</h4>";
                id = item.id.videoId;
                vidThumbimg = '<img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available.">';                   

                $('#results').append("<a onclick=\'getScreenshots(\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+id+"\")'>" + vidTitle + "<br>" + "Published: " +vidPublish + "<br>"+ "Channel: "+vidChannel + "<br>"+ vidThumbimg + "</a><hr>");                      
        })  
    })  
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the `channel_id`, *change the `highlighted letter` as is shown*:

> Channel: Microsoft Hololens
>
> Channel_id: U**C**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g
>
> Uploads (playlist): U**U**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g

Once you have the uploads playlist, you can use this request for get the uploaded videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&playlistId=<UPLOAD_PLAYLIST_ID>&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%2CvideoPublishedAt)%2Csnippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And these are the results:

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 61,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:38:51.000Z",
    "title": "Industry Partner Solutions for Microsoft HoloLens 2"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "FWYcuHUgcng",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:38:51.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:32:14.000Z",
    "title": "Introducing Microsoft HoloLens 2 (Audio Description)"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "NtRGESjKT6M",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:32:14.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:31:30.000Z",
    "title": "Introducing Microsoft HoloLens 2"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "eqFqtAJMtYE",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:31:30.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:39:08.000Z",
    "title": "PACCAR is exploring Dynamics 365 Guides and HoloLens 2 to improve employee onboarding"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "OQDhTtDgir0",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:39:08.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:41:16.000Z",
    "title": "Introducing Dynamics 365 Guides for HoloLens 2"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "V8c3pDKdHEc",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-24T17:41:16.000Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&playlistId=UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%252CvideoPublishedAt)%252Csnippet(publishedAt%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=6&) I made.

N.B, [this channel has 61 uploaded videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g) and the maximun results per page are 50.

This is the entire [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/d8kbostv/).

Comment: i have the request working however, all my links get changed to the last item from the channel lists playlistid.

Comment: @DanielRyan it is possible that you're not making right the loop for the playlistitems or you're overwrite them. I'm trying to replicate the results and just for recommendation: try use comments in your code. Use jsfiddle if you want for create a working example. I know you page works, but, it would be better if you use jsfiddle, also, do not add credentials on it, i.e. your YouTube Data API key.

Comment: I was able to figure it out as it was a problem with my code structure as it was over writing everything. im not sure how i fixed it but playing around with it and removing a function as well as simplifying the way it worked fixed it.