# Why is my call to Youtube V3 API Search:List is not returning the most recent videos?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent youtube video ID that was uploaded to my channel. This is my API request:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MYKEY}&channelId={MYCHANNELID}&part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=date"
```

The request is returning a video from 2017 despite the fact that I have dozens of videos posted before and after 2017.

This request was working correctly about 2 weeks ago. I tried adding the publishedAfter parameter, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/4092887) for get the recent uploaded videos from given channel.

Comment: Thanks. This solution work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the API 'temporary' change made March 15th: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/2494861?hl=en

Comment: Looks like you are right. Switching the request to get the most recent videos in the "upload" playlist worked  as a fix.