# YouTube API v3 Search List - Querying Multiple Channel IDs Not Working

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When including multiple YouTube *channel ids* the response does not return a result.

## Expected

Returning video results from multiple channel ids with the API request.

**Request**

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCiAW4HQiYjpPmyi4v905u1A%2C+UCrFCDzgIucPi7x_OzsYefWQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

## Observed

**Response**

The response is empty.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/-f6JA5_OcXz2RWuH1mpAA2_9mM8\"",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Comment: I think you can only batch call video IDs, not channel IDs. Did you see otherwise in the documentation?

Comment: @Bman70, I have not been able to verify from the documentation whether the channelId accepts one or more ids.

Answer (score 2):

Channel's request accepts multiple channel IDs like below:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCiAW4HQiYjpPmyi4v905u1A%2CUCrFCDzgIucPi7x_OzsYefWQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

But nowadays there no way to get video IDs directly from channels API response, you have to set "part=snippet%2CcontentDetails" in channel request part, and then fetch ID of list uploaded videos in response ("relatedPlaylists" -> "uploads"). Then you can get whole channel's videos ID's by playListItems request: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems

Comment: for retrieve the "uploads" id, just change a single letter in the "channel_id" [as I show in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/4092887).