# Can't retrieve youtube channel videos of some channels

Tags: youtube-api

Some of the channels giving zero videos result even though there are existing videos on those channels. But on some channels it's working fine.

Here is the channel example which is not returning result.

channel id: UCsmyfPVdui2ZjOQSdM6CHWA

My question is, is youtube API v3 not returning result from inactive channels?
Or what is the reason(s) behind this? Thank you so much in advance.

Tried to read youtube API docs. but can't find relating to this issue.

Here is the curl I'm using:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=&channelId=UCsmyfPVdui2ZjOQSdM6CHWA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&pageToken=CDIQAA

NOTE: This is working fine on some channels and not working on some channels too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say for sure why the `search` request is not working with some channels, but, you can try get the uploaded videos from given channel by using the "[youtube.playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list)" request.

> Returns a collection of playlist items that match the API request
>   parameters. You can retrieve all of the playlist items in a specified
>   playlist or retrieve one or more playlist items by their unique IDs.

Here is an example (*using the `channel_id` you provided in your question*):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&playlistId=UUsmyfPVdui2ZjOQSdM6CHWA&fields=items(contentDetails%2FvideoId%2Csnippet(position%2Cthumbnails%2Ctitle)%2Cstatus)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In this request, I'm using the `uploads playlist id` for retrieve the uploaded videos from a given `channel_id` - you can [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/4092887) for more information.

Here is the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatus&playlistId=UUsmyfPVdui2ZjOQSdM6CHWA&fields=items(contentDetails%252FvideoId%252Csnippet(position%252Cthumbnails%252Ctitle)%252Cstatus)&_h=3&) where you can test futher.

Comment: Yes you are right, people can do that. And thank you so much for your comment, but I still want to know the reason behind that.

Comment: @ConstantineAwa-ao, unfortunately, I still don't know the reason and might be possible nobody can give one; this is due it's YouTube, wiith this I mean, they made undocumented changes and sometimes, YouTube Data API wont work as expected. If you still looking for a official reason, I suggest you post your question _(or search a related one)_ on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) = which is _[according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)_: a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. Best of luck.