# Can not fetch video from this channel "UCDtoxgCJVoKp_ImQqWTuUpw"

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a problem trying to fetch videos from this channel:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDtoxgCJVoKp_ImQqWTuUpw
```

I used api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=UCDtoxgCJVoKp_ImQqWTuUpw&publishedBefore=2020-01-31T23:59:59Z&publishedAfter=2019-06-01T00:00:00Z&order=date&key={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

to fetch. I expect the result to contain videos of six months period but I got nothing.

According to the VIDEOS tab at this link

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/businesseventsth/videos?view=0&sort=dd&shelf_id=1
```

There should be more than 10 videos.

Comment: Try use playlistitems request instead for retrieve the videos from a given playlist. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57844778/12511801).

Comment: Thank for the answer. I tried to use route playlistsitem. I think this method can not get data with channel id.

I tried to used route search again. I set param type with video and channel. I can got many data that show in upload video tab. After that I tried it again, I set param type with data, channel, and playlist. I got nothing. I think it like a bug when I set playlist in the param type

Comment: Bigkung, if so, please consider post the issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).