# Get Latest Published YouTube Video URL

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

I hope someone might be able to help me with a problem I'm having.

Currently on our website, we have this page (http://driftgames.life/instagram) which we use as our Instagram bio link URL to let people navigate to many different links. As you will also notice, we embed our latest YouTube video onto this page to make it easier to find.

The issue we're having is that the embed of the video is manual, meaning that oftentimes we forget to update this link meaning it's outdated. As such, what I want to do is try to use the YouTube API in a WordPress plugin to fetch the URL of the latest published video, check it on a cron job and then pull the URL into a shortcode that I can use for the embed.

It would also need to be the last published video, i.e. the one that was made public most recently on the channel, as we publish 2 videos a week and often have videos scheduled in the background.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about this entire process? I've never created a WordPress plugin before, and maybe it's not necessary, but I thought it might be in order to put the URL into a shortcode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!

This site is about coding questions...  "How to set this up" is not a coding question--please read up on making a WordPress Plugin, read up on the Youtube API, give it a good shot and then come back here with your implementations and specific questions...

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the response. I am, however, aware of what the purpose of Stack Overflow is. I've used it in the past, just not under this account. Also, I have played around with the YouTube API to see how I can try and find the data I'm looking to extract, but unsuccessfully. As such, my question is for assistance on that, if anyone has managed to do so yet. The WP plugin piece is almost an aside, but the piece re: trying to use the YT API to get the URL is something I need coding assistance on in terms of the API's correct usage.

Answer (score 3):

Use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3?hl=en) and select the [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) request.

You need:

- The `channel_id` of the YouTube channel you want to get the lastest published video.
- Get the `upload_playlist`- [as I've explained in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/4092887).
- An `API_KEY` - which is needed for use the YouTube Data API.

Then, you can use this following URL for retrieve the latest published video in that channel:

URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&playlistId=UU1A_rSUOukzgb3XOJoZ9EMA&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%2CvideoPublishedAt)%2Csnippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))&maxResults=1
```

Where:

- **`playlistid`**: is the `upload_playlist` - in this case, **`UU1A_rSUOukzgb3XOJoZ9EMA`** - which is the YouTube channel of the website you posted in your question.
- **`key`**: the YouTube API key you need to provide for consume the API.
- **`maxResults`**: parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5. I've used here: **`1`**.

And these are the results:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-08-19T16:14:56Z",
        "title": "DRIFT MASTERS RIGA | BEHIND THE SCENES EXCLUSIVE!"
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "videoId": "TAMNp524BS4",
        "videoPublishedAt": "2020-08-20T19:00:05Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```