# Optimisation of google api requests to retrieve data from youtube videos

Tags: optimization, google-api, get, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to build a website with a section that displays the last video of a youtube channel and the thumbnails and titles of the next 9 most recent videos. The problem I'm having is that I consume the quota of requests just by testing the website.

[image: This is how the website looks]

To get this information I use Google's API. I retrieve the last 10 videos of the channel as follows:

```
<?PHP
include('global_variables.php');
$randomNumber = rand(2,10);
$randomKey = "api.key$randomNumber";
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=".$GLOBALS['api_key']."&part=snippet&channelId=".$GLOBALS['channel_id']."&order=date&maxResults=".$GLOBALS['videos_in_playlist']);
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $data;
?>
```

I call this PHP file in these ways:

```
// TO LOAD PLAYING YOUTUBE VIDEO

    function loadVideo(iframe) {
        $.getJSON("load_playing_video.php",
            function(data) {
                var videoNumber = (iframe.getAttribute('vnum') ? Number(iframe.getAttribute('vnum')) : 0);
                iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://youtube.com/embed/" + data.items[videoNumber].id.videoId+ "?controls=1&autoplay=1&color=white");

                // PLACE VIDEO TITLE
                $("#playing-video-title").html(data.items[videoNumber].snippet.title);

                // PLACE VIDEO DESCRIPTION
                $("#playing-video-description").html(data.items[videoNumber].snippet.description);
            }
        );

    }
    loadVideo(document.querySelector("#playing-video"));
    
// TO LOAD THUMBNAILS AND TITLES ON SIDEBAR

    $.getJSON("load_playing_video.php",
        function(data) {
            for (var index = 0; index < <?php echo $GLOBALS['videos_in_playlist']?>; index++) {
                var videoImage = data.items[index].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                var title = data.items[index].snippet.title;
                var imgId = "#playlist-thumbnail" + index;
                var titleId = "#playlist-title" + index;
                document.querySelector(imgId).setAttribute("src",videoImage);
                document.querySelector(titleId).innerHTML = title;
            } 
        }
    );
```

I was hoping someone could help me optimise the number of requests I do.
And if someone knows how I could increase the quota of requests (even if I have to pay) I would really appreciate some guidelines.

Thank you!!

Comment: I should also comment that when a video from the sidebar is clicked the loadVideo function is triggered. This is why I'm currently using the same request for both.

Comment: Cardona Polo, [read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531425/4092887) - it might help you. Search requests consume more quota. replace it.

Comment: I would also cache the results for X minutes so you're not calling the API every page load.