# YouTube API - Get all videos of channel with more than 500 videos

Tags: python, pandas, youtube

I want to get a list with all `video_ids` from a certain youtube channel. This channel uploaded 1230 videos and 17 livestreams (23/09/2022). I know the youtube api is restricted to only 500 results. So I wanted to use the `publishedBefore`-parameter to get more than these 500 results.

When I use my code, I only get 551 results. Do I have a mistake in my code? I can't see a systemtic mistake in which videos are not included.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import datetime

api_key = '...'
channel_id = 'UCXDi1F7Q-cJQ4mGGavtfYRQ'


# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['channel_id',
                           'video_id',
                           'video_title'
                           'published_date',
                           'type'])


# first request
url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&key=' + api_key
response = requests.get(url=url).json()
total_results = response['pageInfo']['totalResults']

# If there are more than 50 results, the response gives back a nextPageToken to get the other results, so we need to save this Token
if 'nextPageToken' not in response:
    page_token = []
elif 'nextPageToken' in response:
    page_token = response['nextPageToken']

# save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
for i in response['items']:

    channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
    video_id = i['id']['videoId']
    published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
    video_title = i['snippet']['title']
    vid_type = i['id']['kind']

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
        'channel_id': channel_id,
        'video_id': video_id,
        'video_title': video_title,
        'published_date': published_date,
        'type': vid_type
    }])], ignore_index=True)

# CHANNELS WITH <50 VIDEOS
if total_results < 500 and page_token == []:

    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\...\\data\\video_ids_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')

# CHANNELS WITH >50 AND <500 VIDEOS
elif total_results < 500 and page_token != []:
    # with the while loop we get maximum 500 results
    while page_token != []:
        # make the second call for the next results with the nextPageToken
        url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&pageToken=' + page_token + '&key=' + api_key

        response = requests.get(url=url).json()

        # If there are more than 50 results, the response gives back a nextPageToken to get the other results, so we need to save this Token
        if 'nextPageToken' not in response:
            page_token = []
        elif 'nextPageToken' in response:
            page_token = response['nextPageToken']

        # save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
        for i in response['items']:
            channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
            video_id = i['id']['videoId']
            published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
            video_title = i['snippet']['title']
            vid_type = i['id']['kind']

            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
                'channel_id': channel_id,
                'video_id': video_id,
                'video_title': video_title,
                'published_date': published_date,
                'type': vid_type
            }])], ignore_index=True)

    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\...\\data\\video_ids_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')

# CHANNELS WITH >500 VIDEOS
# to get more than 500 results we need another loop - we will do this by using the published_date variable
else:
    while page_token != []:
        # make the second call for the next results with the nextPageToken
        url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&pageToken=' + page_token + '&key=' + api_key

        response = requests.get(url=url).json()

        # If there are more than 50 results, the response gives back a nextPageToken to get the other results, so we need to save this Token
        if 'nextPageToken' not in response:
            page_token = []
        elif 'nextPageToken' in response:
            page_token = response['nextPageToken']

        # save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
        for i in response['items']:
            channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
            video_id = i['id']['videoId']
            published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
            video_title = i['snippet']['title']
            vid_type = i['id']['kind']

            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
                'channel_id': channel_id,
                'video_id': video_id,
                'video_title': video_title,
                'published_date': published_date,
                'type': vid_type
            }])], ignore_index=True)

    else:
        url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&publishedBefore=' + published_date + '&key=' + api_key

        response = requests.get(url=url).json()

        # If there are more than 50 results, the response gives back a nextPageToken to get the other results, so we need to save this Token
        if 'nextPageToken' not in response:
            page_token = []
        elif 'nextPageToken' in response:
            page_token = response['nextPageToken']

        # save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
        for i in response['items']:
            channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
            video_id = i['id']['videoId']
            published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
            video_title = i['snippet']['title']
            vid_type = i['id']['kind']

            df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
                'channel_id': channel_id,
                'video_id': video_id,
                'video_title': video_title,
                'published_date': published_date,
                'type': vid_type
            }])], ignore_index=True)

        df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\...\\data\\video_ids_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I found no solution, but another approach to get the videos. Just use the `publishedBefore`-parameter. Now I got 1114 results but these are still not the full results...

```
# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['channel_id',
                           'video_id',
                           'video_title'
                           'published_date',
                           'type'])


# first request
url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&key=' + api_key
response = requests.get(url=url).json()
total_results = response['pageInfo']['totalResults']

# save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
for i in response['items']:

    channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
    video_id = i['id']['videoId']
    published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
    video_title = i['snippet']['title']
    vid_type = i['id']['kind']

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
        'channel_id': channel_id,
        'video_id': video_id,
        'video_title': video_title,
        'published_date': published_date,
        'type': vid_type
    }])], ignore_index=True)

while df['video_id'][len(df)-1] != df['video_id'][len(df)-2]:
    url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + channel_id + '&maxResults=50&order=date&type=video&publishedBefore=' + published_date + '&key=' + api_key

    response = requests.get(url=url).json()
    total_results = response['pageInfo']['totalResults']

    for i in response['items']:
        channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
        video_id = i['id']['videoId']
        published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
        video_title = i['snippet']['title']
        vid_type = i['id']['kind']

        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
            'channel_id': channel_id,
            'video_id': video_id,
            'video_title': video_title,
            'published_date': published_date,
            'type': vid_type
        }])], ignore_index=True)

# because the last row is a duplicate we need to delete the last row
df.drop(df.tail(1).index, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\...\\data\\video_ids_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')
```

If I try my methods with another channel which has only 28 videos uploaded everything seems to work.

Use this ID: `channel_id:'UCWz3hMEDel0NGkR4jue2q1A'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "`search.list`", you could consider use "`playlistitems.list`" instead for retrieve the uploaded videos of the said channel.

Check the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/12511801) for more details.