# Unable to check if new youtube video is uploaded

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I want to know when someone upload a new video to his / her youtube channel 'https://www.youtube.com/@some-name-xyz'.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Replace with your API key
api_key = "my-api-key"

# Replace with the Youtuber's username or channel ID
channel_id = "some-name-xyz"

# Build the YouTube API client
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

# Call the search.list method to retrieve the latest video uploaded by the Youtuber
search_response = youtube.search().list(
    part="snippet",
    channelId=channel_id,
    maxResults=1,
    order="date",
    type="video"
).execute() # <- getting error here

# some more code
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Mahesh\workspaces\youtube-checker-dl\check-yt.py", line 20, in <module>
    ).execute()
  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\ProgramFiles\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=%40some-name-xyz&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key=my-api-key&alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "[{'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">
```

What I am missing here?

[Reference 1](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py),
[Reference 2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: [Subscribe to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) might better fit your needs.

Comment: You could instead use `PlaylistItems:list` for get the uploaded videos from certain channel - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031047/12511801)